# XML Parsing Error - XmlHttpObj is null

Tags: php, ajax, xml, mysqli

Since moving to a https server and updating code, I'm having problems with cascading dropdown boxes that were previously working.

I get an XML Parsing Error: no element found, as well as an error telling me that XmlHttpObj.responseXML is null.

I have had some errors relating to updating the mysqli sections, and from what I have been able to work out I think the problem might be with the query. However, this is the same query that I have been using, and which has been working fine. So, I'm really not sure what is wrong here.

Ajax function causing error:

```
function StateChangeHandler(){
    // state ==4 indicates receiving response data from server is completed
    if(XmlHttpObj.readyState == 4 && XmlHttpObj.status == 200){
         populateCbo(XmlHttpObj.responseXML.documentElement);
    }
}
```

XML page which is returning the null value:

```
<?php
    // simple data provider for a cascading dropdown

    Header("Content-type: text/xml");
    include("db_setup.php");
    session_start();
    $db = $_SESSION['db_id'];
    $con = mysqli_connect( C_DB_HOST, C_DB_NAME, C_DB_PASSWORD, $db );// Opens database

    // get query string params

    $parent = $_GET['parent'];
    $level = $_GET['level'];

    //Create query of other level records
    $qry = "SELECT field1, field2 FROM table WHERE field3 = '".$parent."' and field4 = '".$level."'";

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $qry);
    mysqli_free_result($result);

    // build xml content for JavaScript interpreter
    $xml = "<mxml>";
    $xml = $xml . '<parent_level name="0">';
    $xml = $xml . '<child_level id="0"> </child_level>';
    $xml = $xml . '</parent_level>';
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $id = $row['field1'];

        $value1= $row['field2'];
        $value = str_replace("&", "&", $value1);

        $xml = $xml . '<parent_level name="'.$parent.'">';
        $xml = $xml . '<child_level id="'.$id.'">'.$value.'</child_level>';
        $xml = $xml . '</parent_level>';
    }

    if (!$result) {
    printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con)); //THIS IS NOT PRINTING ANY ERRORS
    exit();
}

    $xml = $xml . "</mxml>";
    // send xml to client
    echo( $xml );
?>
```

Comment: Where is `$valueA` set which is used in the query?

Comment: You may also find that your `session_start()` needs to be at the very start of this script (before `header()`)

Comment: Most likely the XML output from your PHP script is broken. Use the developer tools of your browser to check the it. I would suggest to use an XML Api (DOM or XMLWriter) to generate the XML output or at least escape the values using `htmlspecialchars()`.

Comment: $valueA was incorrectly labelled for this example, sorry about that - have corrected it above now. 
I tried moving session_start() to the top - didn't solve the problem, but gave me a slightly different error which led me to an answer:
mysqli_free_result($result); needed moving to after the while loop, as it discards the result: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.free.php